# LilyPond: auto horizontal space for dynamic text

Tags: lilypond

I am missing something basic, I spent hours searching for docs for no avail. Sometimes LilyPond can be really frustrating.

Look at this picture:

[image: overlapping ppp]

Obviously, ppp overlaps with the bar line. According to documentation, I tried using `DynamicText.extra-spacing-width`, but it has zero effect. Here's the code:

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "italiano"

common = {
    \key sol \minor
    \time 4/4
    \tempo "Largo [Широко]"
}

right = \relative do'' {
    \key sol \major
    sol8 (fad re mi sol fad re4) |
    sol8 (fad re mib sol fad re4)
}

left = \relative do' {
    \key sol \major
    sol,8 (re' si' re,) sol, (re' do' re,) |
    sol, (re' sib' re,) sol, (re' do' re,) |
}

dynamics = {
    s1 |
    \override DynamicText.extra-spacing-width = #'(-1 . 1)
    s8 \ppp s8 s8 s8 s8 s8 s4
}

\score {
    \new PianoStaff <<
        \new Staff = "right" \right
        \new Dynamics \dynamics
        \new Staff = "left" { \clef bass \left }
    >>
}
```

If I move `\override ...` right in the front of `\ppp`, it doesn't overlap, but LilyPond complains then with "Unattached AbsoluteDynamicEvent".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run into this a lot.  I find that using an X-offset works:

```
dynamics = {
    s1 |
    \override DynamicText.X-offset = 0
    s8 \ppp s8 s8 s8 s8 s8 s4
}
```

Comment: Very intuitive :)

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug to me. For `extra-spacing-width` to work, both of the objects that should avoid each other must have some width and some height. You can visualize the "skylines" that LilyPond uses for distancing using

```
#(ly:set-option 'debug-skylines)
\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    \override PaperColumn.stencil = #ly:separation-item::print
    \override NonMusicalPaperColumn.stencil = #ly:separation-item::print
  }
}
```

(it's expected that the ones from the lower staff are vertically off by some amount; horizontal skylines are built before line breaking, when we only have an estimation of the distance between the two staves).

This gives:

[image: skylines]

You can see that the problem is the SpanBar not receiving skylines; this is because it has no height, so the interval on which it is considered to collide is not known.

For now a workaround seems to be

```
\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    \override SpanBar.Y-extent = #axis-group-interface::height
    \override SpanBar.meta.object-callbacks.pure-Y-common =
      #ly:axis-group-interface::calc-pure-y-common
    \override SpanBar.meta.object-callbacks.pure-relevant-grobs =
      #ly:axis-group-interface::calc-pure-relevant-grobs
  }
}
```

(there must be a reason why it is not in the current code, so be aware that it could have bad effects in cases that I have no considered).

Comment: Would this same SpanBar issue explain the problem is this question?: [LilyPond: parenthesized hairpin](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/116313/70803).

Comment: Not fully. Spanners do not participate in horizontal spacing the same way as items with skylines, only via minimum-distance and minimum-distance-after-break as far as I can see. At least, my pending merge request https://gitlab.com/lilypond/lilypond/-/merge_requests/842 does not solve the case`\version "2.23.4"

\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    \override BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-10 . 10)
    \override Parentheses.font-size = 10
  }
}

\new StaffGroup <<
  { c1\parenthesize\< 1\! }
  { c1 1 }`
>>

Comment: I don't understand practically anything in this post. I don't understand the code, the term "skylines", how to interpret the picture, and what is SpanBar.

Comment: Ok,

- SpanBar is the grob that draws the part of the bar line between staves. To understand, try

\version "2.22.1" \new StaffGroup \with { \override SpanBar.color = red } << { c1 } { c1 } >>

- Skylines are outlines of objects. They are used to resolve collisions. You can view them as pieces of metal in the score, with space between them; LilyPond could compress the score until the pieces are touching each other. This applies to horizontal and vertical spacing.

- The code is not supposed to be understandable. It's a horrible low-level hack.

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra Your SpanBar workaround has a strange side effect. It changes the paging; the resulting score has very sparse systems on the page.