# Lilypond: placing parentheses around grace notes and slurs

Tags: lilypond

How can I put parentheses around a grace note?

I would also like to be able to put small parentheses around a slur.  I have been using a dotted slur instead, but don't really like the look of it.

Comment: You might check if this post offers any clues: [LilyPond: parenthesized hairpin](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/116313/70803).

Comment: Thank you. I can't yet tell if there are any clues in this---it is complex!  I'm hoping there will be a more straightforward path towards the solution but I appreciate the reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As can be seen here:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/inside-the-staff#parentheses
... there is a command for parentheses: `\parenthesize`

Simply place this command just before the note or symbol you want parenthesised:

```
\new Staff {
    c'' 
    \acciaccatura { \parenthesize d'8 } c'4 
    d''4 \parenthesize ( c''4) |
}
```

[image: excerpt of score with grace note and slur parenthesised]

If you need to change the padding or size of the parentheses you can use the following overrides:
`\override Parentheses.padding = #0.1`
`\override Parentheses.font-size = #-4`

Comment: Thank you!  I tried various placements of the parenthesize command and couldn't find the ones that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Elements In Space’s answer:

In such cases we might occasionally want to parenthesize or bracket the whole note instead of just the note head. I’ve taken this opportunity to write a little function that does exactly that:

```
% modification for scm/stencil.scm:parenthesize-stencil that allows to specify direction
#(define* (parenthesize-stencil
           stencil half-thickness width angularity padding #:optional (direction CENTER))
  "Add parentheses around @var{stencil}, returning a new stencil."
  (let* ((y-extent (ly:stencil-extent stencil Y))
         (lp ((@@ (lily) make-parenthesis-stencil)
              y-extent half-thickness width angularity 1))
         (rp ((@@ (lily) make-parenthesis-stencil)
              y-extent half-thickness width angularity -1)))
    (if (<= direction CENTER)
        (set! stencil (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge stencil X LEFT lp padding)))
    (if (>= direction CENTER)
        (set! stencil (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge stencil X RIGHT rp padding)))
    stencil))

% modification for scm/stencil.scm:bracketify-stencil that allows to specify direction
#(define* (bracketify-stencil stil axis thick protrusion padding #:optional (direction CENTER))
  "Add brackets around @var{stil}, producing a new stencil."

  (let* ((ext (ly:stencil-extent stil axis))
         (lb (ly:bracket axis ext thick protrusion))
         (rb (ly:bracket axis ext thick (- protrusion))))
    (if (>= direction CENTER)
        (set! stil
              (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge stil (other-axis axis) 1 rb padding)))
    (if (<= direction CENTER)
        (set! stil
              (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge stil (other-axis axis) -1 lb padding)))
    stil))

%%% Change Stem.stencil to #(parenthesize-note ...) to paranthesize a whole note. Use
%%% key arguments to change details e.g. #(parenthesize-note #:thickness 0.2)
%%% We are not directly using this to calculate stencil, but rather use this in
%%% Stem.before-line-breaking, as else we get circular dependency warnings for
%%% Stem.Y-extent with Flags.
%%%
%%% WARNING: THIS IS NOT COMPATIBLE WITH BEAMS!
%%% THIS WILL TRY TO ADD EXTRA SPACE TO THE STEM SO IT DOES NOT COLLIDE!
%%% THIS MIGHT PRODUCE AWKWARD RESULTS!
#(define* (parenthesize-note #:key
                             (addleft 0)
                             (addright 0)
                             (addtop 0)
                             (addbottom 0)
                             (thickness 0.2)
                             (width 0.4)
                             (angularity 0)
                             (direction CENTER)
                             (bracket #f)
                             (bracket-protrusion 0.25)
                             (bracket-padding 0.1))
   (lambda (grob)
     (let* ((orig (ly:grob-property grob 'stencil))
            (orig (if (not (ly:stencil? orig)) empty-stencil orig))
            ; Collect all grobs belonging to note from Stem (Flag, Heads, Accidentals)
            (flag (ly:grob-object grob 'flag))
            (trem-flag (ly:grob-object grob 'tremolo-flag))
            (heads (ly:grob-object grob 'note-heads))
            (heads (ly:grob-array->list heads))
            (accidentals (map (lambda (head) (ly:grob-object head 'accidental-grob))
                              heads))
            (dots (map (lambda (head) (ly:grob-object head 'dot))
                       heads))
            (all-add-grobs (append (list flag trem-flag) heads accidentals dots))
            (all-add-grobs (filter (lambda (x) (not (null? x))) all-add-grobs))
            ; Determine X extents of each such grob relative to Paper Column (second X parent of Stem).
            ; This is necessariy as Accidentals do not have the Note Column as parent
            (all-x-exts (map (lambda (g) (ly:grob-extent g (ly:grob-parent (ly:grob-parent grob X) X) X))
                             all-add-grobs))
            ; Determine Y extents of each such grob relative to Vertical Axis Group (second Y parent of Stem).
            ; This is necessariy as Tremolo Flags do not have the Note Column as parent
            (all-y-exts (map (lambda (g) (ly:grob-extent g (ly:grob-parent (ly:grob-parent grob Y) Y) Y))
                             all-add-grobs))
            (all-x-exts (filter (lambda (x) (not (null? x))) all-x-exts))
            (all-y-exts (filter (lambda (x) (not (null? x))) all-y-exts))
            ; Add extent of this stencil
            (ext-x (ly:grob-extent grob (ly:grob-parent grob X) X))
            (ext-y (ly:grob-extent grob (ly:grob-parent grob Y) Y))
            ; Get offset of grob
            (off-x (ly:grob-property grob 'X-offset))
            (off-y (ly:grob-property grob 'Y-offset))
            ; Add stencil extents
            (all-x-exts (cons ext-x all-x-exts))
            (all-y-exts (cons ext-y all-y-exts))
            ; unify extents
            (ext-x (reduce (lambda (x y) (interval-union x y)) '(0 0) all-x-exts))
            (ext-y (reduce (lambda (x y) (interval-union x y)) '(0 0) all-y-exts))
            ; correct for offset
            (ext-x (cons (- (car ext-x) off-x) (- (cdr ext-x) off-x)))
            (ext-y (cons (- (car ext-y) off-y) (- (cdr ext-y) off-y)))
            ; extend by padding
            (ext-x (cons (- (car ext-x) addleft) (+ (cdr ext-x) addright)))
            (ext-y (cons (- (car ext-y) addbottom) (+ (cdr ext-y) addtop)))
            ; Change dimensions of bar line
            (orig-box (ly:stencil-outline orig (make-filled-box-stencil ext-x ext-y)))
            (pstc (parenthesize-stencil orig-box (/ thickness 2) width angularity 0 direction))
            (bktstc (bracketify-stencil orig-box Y thickness bracket-protrusion bracket-padding direction))
            (newstc (if bracket bktstc pstc))
            ; Try to add more space if necessary
            (extra-sw (ly:grob-property grob 'extra-spacing-width '(0 . 0)))
            (new-ext (ly:stencil-extent newstc X))
            (old-ext (ly:stencil-extent orig X))
            (diff1 (- (car new-ext) (car old-ext)))
            (diff2 (- (cdr new-ext) (cdr old-ext)))
            (new-extra-sw (cons (+ (car extra-sw) diff1) (+ (cdr extra-sw) diff2))))
            
       (if bracket
           (ly:grob-set-property! grob 'stencil bktstc)
           (ly:grob-set-property! grob 'stencil pstc))
       (ly:grob-set-property! grob 'extra-spacing-width new-extra-sw))))

#(define (alist->arglist alist)
   (define (impl alist)
     (if (null? alist)
         '()
         (append (list (symbol->keyword (caar alist)) (cdar alist))
                 (alist->arglist (cdr alist)))))
   ; If one key is duplicate #:key arguments will use the last one
   ; as the assoc-get-behaviour is opposite we reverse the alist
   (impl (reverse alist)))

#(define (list-of-pairs? l)
   (define (all-pairs? l)
     (if (null? l)
         #t
         (and (pair? (car l)) (all-pairs? (cdr l)))))
   (and (list? l) (all-pairs? l)))

parenthesizeNote =
#(define-music-function (opts mus)
   ((list-of-pairs? '()) ly:music?)
   #{
     \once\override Stem.before-line-breaking =
     #(apply parenthesize-note (alist->arglist opts))
     #mus
   #})

parenthesizeNoteLeft =
#(define-music-function (opts mus)
   ((list-of-pairs? '()) ly:music?)
   (parenthesizeNote (append opts `((direction . ,LEFT))) mus))

parenthesizeNoteRight =
#(define-music-function (opts mus)
   ((list-of-pairs? '()) ly:music?)
   (parenthesizeNote (append opts `((direction . ,RIGHT))) mus))

bracketNote =
#(define-music-function (opts mus)
   ((list-of-pairs? '()) ly:music?)
   (parenthesizeNote (append opts `((bracket . #t))) mus))

bracketNoteLeft =
#(define-music-function (opts mus)
   ((list-of-pairs? '()) ly:music?)
   (parenthesizeNote (append opts `((bracket . #t) (direction . ,LEFT))) mus))

bracketNoteRight =
#(define-music-function (opts mus)
   ((list-of-pairs? '()) ly:music?)
   (parenthesizeNote (append opts `((bracket . #t) (direction . ,RIGHT))) mus))




%%% EXAMPLES

\new Staff {
    c'' 
    \acciaccatura { \parenthesizeNote d'8 } c'4 
    d''4 \parenthesize ( c''4) |
}

\new Staff {
    c'' 
    \acciaccatura { \bracketNote d'8 } c'4 
    d''4 \parenthesize ( c''4) |
}

\new Staff {
  \parenthesizeNote a'
  \parenthesizeNote 8\noBeam
  \parenthesizeNote 16\noBeam
  \parenthesizeNote 16\noBeam
  \parenthesizeNote ais'16
  r8.
  \parenthesizeNoteLeft a'4 g' f' e' \parenthesizeNoteRight d'
}

\new Staff {
  \bracketNote a'
  \bracketNote 8\noBeam
  \bracketNote 16\noBeam
  \bracketNote 16\noBeam
  \bracketNote ais'16
  r8.
  \bracketNoteLeft a'4 g' f' e' \bracketNoteRight d'
}

\new Staff {
  \parenthesizeNote <c' d' f'>1
  \bracketNote #'((addright . 2)) 4
  \bracketNote 4...
  \bracketNote 4:32
}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

EDIT: Updated code to also handle dots and tremolo flags.

EDIT2: Updated code to proper handle chords, also allow note with no stem (hole not, \omit Stem)